# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error after delete one database

Tags: oracle11g, protocols, tns, ora-12560

i have `oracle11g desktop`. For my project I create 3 databases via configuration assistant tools. Then I delete one of them
and after this I have the error: `ora-12560`.
By mistake both of my databases have the same pasword, 
for example: when i want to connect one of these data bases with system user, i have one pasword and perhaps the databases dont know connect which one.

I start all services
set `oracle_sid=orcl`.
I run `lsnrctl`
`tnsping` check `tansname.ora` &  `my listener.ora`
and I logon with `sysdba@oracle_sid`

but i have this error again

pleas help me
tnx

Comment: What doe a password have to do with any of this? That is not your problem. There is something wrong in your tnsnames.ora file. Try running sqlplus with the entire TNS entry on the command line like this: sqlplus <username>/<password>@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL= TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<port>)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED )(SERVICE_NAME=<sid>)))    replace parameters as needed

Comment: tanx for ur answer I try this in sqlplus but faced error=ora-12154:tns:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

and when used name of host instede of IP faced error =ora-12545:connect failed because target host or object dose not exist.

please help regard

Answer (score 1):

sounds like the database is not up. you probably restarted your machine and the instance is not set to autostart

```
C:\Documents and Settings\tkyte>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Sep 6 15:43:55 2007

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

scott%ORA10GR1> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

C:\Documents and Settings\tkyte>net stop oracleserviceora10gr1
The OracleServiceORA10GR1 service is stopping.........
The OracleServiceORA10GR1 service was stopped successfully.


C:\Documents and Settings\tkyte>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Sep 6 15:44:35 2007

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

C:\Documents and Settings\tkyte>net start oracleserviceora10gr1
The OracleServiceORA10GR1 service is starting..........
The OracleServiceORA10GR1 service was started successfully.


C:\Documents and Settings\tkyte>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Sep 6 15:45:12 2007

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

scott%ORA10GR1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error after delete a db (in the window enviroment) and I resolved as following

the first way:

C:> SET ORACLE_SID = SID NAME

the second way:

Use regedit locate to path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_HOME_NAME 
update ORACLE_SID =

refer at: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-EC18C4A6-3BA5-4C14-9D76-B0DD62FEFFF2.htm#ADMQS12369